# How can I get my PostgreSQL server to wrok?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.017 Sec
2023-07-26 18:16:20,262: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.

- Serving Flask app 'pgadmin'
- Debug mode: off

2023-07-26 18:16:20,262: WARNING    werkzeug:   Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web server instead.
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

```
It says PgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted. I tried deleting, uninstalling still nothing. I'm using windows 11. PosgtreSQL 15. I used the pgAdmin 4 that comes with it. I then deleted the pgAdmin 4 and downloaded pgAdmin 4 7v4. It started but it doesn't connect. As for the installation process, I installed directly from the postgreSQL app with the installer and followed all the right steps.
```

Comment: `pgAdmin4` != Postgres. `pgAdmin4` is just a GUI client and the issue is with it's Web server component not Postgres. Either use another client to connect to Postgres or if possible use the Desktop client version. More information is needed. Add to your question **as text**: 1) OS and version. 2) pgAdmin4 version 3) How you are installing it.

Comment: I also tried connecting from aws rds it also didn't connect

Comment: *I also tried connecting from aws rds it also didn't connect* doesn't make sense, RDS is a database you connect to it not from it. You will need to be more specific and also answer the questions in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm using windows 11. PosgtreSQL 15. I used the pgAdmin that comes with it. I then deleted the pgAdmin 4 and downloaded pgAdmin 4 7v4. It started but it doesn't connect. As for the installation process, I installed directly from the postgreSQL app with the installer and followed all the right steps.

Comment: Per previous request add this information as update to your question so other folks don't have to dig through the comments  for relevant information.

Comment: Version 7.4 seems to be buggy in general. I would try uninstalling it and using version 7.3.

Comment: I've added it now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to solve it. I went to delete the pgAdmin 4, it prompts you to select the app and unistall, then it asks you if you want to uninstall the entire app or individual apps. I selected indivial apps and only uninstalled the pgAdmin4. then I searched pgAdmin 4 on the internet and downloaded it and it worked.